# PHP key=value string to array

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I have a string `category=45&format=1` that I want to convert into a key=value array.

Does anyone know if there is a quick way of doing this without having to write a function that explode's the `&` and then the `=` * snore *

Comment: I predict that there would be no less than half a dozen answers, only 25% of them right, though

Comment: in fact, such a function you are too scare to write, will took you the same time as it took you to write this question. So, - no *real* time saving.

Comment: As there is in fact a native function the saving is in performance!

Comment: oh. don't talk of the performance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're dealing with the URL query format: `parse_str`

```
parse_str('category=45&format=1', $array);
```

http://php.net/parse_str

Comment: I knew there was something native!

Answer (score 4):

If it's a query string or doesn't contain special characters you can use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).